# How can i avoid from showing another Form when closing the program Form1?

Tags: c#

In the closing event i have this:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            FormIsClosing = true;
            KeysValuesUpdate();
        }
```

FormIsClosing is a flag.

Then this is the KeysValuesUpdate function:

```
public void KeysValuesUpdate()
        {
            using (var w = new StreamWriter(keywords_path_file))
            {
                if (FormIsClosing == true)
                crawlLocaly1 = new CrawlLocaly(this);
                crawlLocaly1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                if (FormIsClosing == true)
                DialogResult dr = crawlLocaly1.ShowDialog(this);
                if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    if (LocalyKeyWords.ContainsKey(mainUrl))
                    {
                        LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Clear();
                        LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Add(crawlLocaly1.getText());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl] = new List<string>();
                        LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Add(crawlLocaly1.getText());
                    }
                    Write(w);
                    ClearListBox();
                }
                if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    Write(w);
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is if im doing just if (FormIsClosing == true) the the next line i want not to take effect im getting error on it:

Error   1   Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement
And the line after it : dr is unsigned.

If im doing:

```
if (FormIsClosing == true)
{
                    DialogResult dr = crawlLocaly1.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Then dr is unsign on this line: if (dr == DialogResult.OK)

What i want to archive is that if i close my application just dont show this dialog first.
And the line that show the dialog is: DialogResult dr = crawlLocaly1.ShowDialog(this);

Comment: Just move your `if` statement down a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update from OP's comment**

Here's how you can display the form when the program is not closing:

```
            DialogResult dr = DialogResult.None;//Increase accessibility domain, setup a good default value
            if (FormIsClosing != true)
            {
              dr = crawlLocaly1.ShowDialog(this);
            }
```

Comment: I did a mistake the onlyl ine i want not to take action when closing the program is:  DialogResult dr = crawlLocaly1.ShowDialog(this); i dont want it to show the dialog again when closing the program.

Comment: Updated my question with what i did now.

Comment: P.Brian.Mackey i tried it but then dr in the line under it is not signed. So im getting error on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition refers only to next line as you have put nothing in brackets.

This should work, I guess:

```
        using (var w = new StreamWriter(keywords_path_file))
        {
            if (FormIsClosing == true)
            {
            crawlLocaly1 = new CrawlLocaly(this);
            crawlLocaly1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            DialogResult dr = crawlLocaly1.ShowDialog(this);
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (LocalyKeyWords.ContainsKey(mainUrl))
                {
                    LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Clear();
                    LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Add(crawlLocaly1.getText());
                }
                else
                {
                    LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl] = new List<string>();
                    LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Add(crawlLocaly1.getText());
                }
                Write(w);
                ClearListBox();
            }
            if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                Write(w);
            }
            }
        }
```